# Swift String.Index variable doesn't have enough bits

Tags: swift, string, indexing

I'm trying to work with some Swift strings. I know that Swift won't take `text[0]` since it's not a `String.Index` type.

However, Xcode is throwing me an error on this code:

```
let text = "Word"
let i: String.Index = text.startIndex
```

Xcode says:

> `i` does not have *enough bits to represent the passed value*

...when it should since it's the correct type.

What is going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Btw Swift is a type inferred language. There is no need to explicitly set the resulting type in this case.

Comment: This piece of code is fine, maybe you are doing something else. Post complete code.